# Eigenvector of stochastic matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stochastic-matrices

> $P$ is stochastic matrix, $v$ is stochastic vector, $\frac{1}{n}(v + vP + vP^{2} + \cdots + vP^{n}) \to u$. Prove that $uP = u$.

I understood that I need to show that u is eigenvector with eigenvalue 1 and understood why 1 is always eigenvalue, but can’t understand what I should do to prove what I need. Thank you for help.

Comment: Is $P$ row-stochastic or column-stochastic?

Comment: This is just stating that for any initial distribution $v$, the distribution of $X_n$ converges to $u$. $u$ is an eigenvector because it is a stationary distribution for $\{X_n\}$.

Comment: @Math1000, how we show that u is a stationary distribution?

Comment: The question doesn't seem correct. Are you sure it is $v+vP+\cdots+vP^n$ rather than $vP^n$ that approaches $u$?

Comment: @user1551, yes :(

Comment: If $\ v\ $ is a stochastic (row) vector and $\ P\ $ a (row) stochastic matrix, then $\ v+vP+vP^2+\dots +vP^n\ $ cannot converge as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $, because $\ \left(v+vP+vP^2+\dots +vP^n\right)\mathbb{1}=n+1\ $, where $\ \mathbb{1}\ $ is a column vector of ones. I suspect there's a typo in the question, and it should be something like $\ \frac{1}{n}\left(v+vP+vP^2+\dots +vP^n\right)\rightarrow u\ $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera, you are right, I am sorry, I edited, thank you!

Comment: @lonzaleggiera, what to do know? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\ \frac{1}{n}\left(v + vP+vP^2+ \dots+vP^n\right)P-\frac{1}{n}\left(v + vP+vP^2+ \dots+vP^n\right)\\
=\frac{1}{n}\left(vP^{n+1}-v\right)\ . $$
What does this converge to?

Comment: How can we do $vP^{n + 1} - v$ if we don’t know the size of $vP^{n + 1}$ and $v$?

Comment: You know  $\ vP^{n+1}\ $ must be stochastic, because $\ v\  $ and $\ P\ $ are stochastic.

Comment: Yes, i know it... but it didn’t make me move to a solution

Comment: If $\ w_n\ $ is *any* sequence of *stochastic* vectors, what must $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{w_n}{n}\ $ be? (keep in mind that the entries of a stochastic vector are all non-negative and sum to $1$, so none of them can exceed $1$)

Comment: So $vP^{n + 1}$ is a row with elements sum = 1, v is also, so $vP^{n + 1} - v$ has elements sum = 0 - does it mean what I need?

Comment: The sum itself is largely irrelevant.  The point is that if all the entries of $\ w_n\ $ lie between $0$ and $1$, then $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{w_n}{n}=0\ $.

Comment: Thank you so-so much for your help! I understand correctly that $\frac{w_{n}}{n} \to 0$ means that if $\frac{w_{n}}{n}$ is $(w_{1}, w_{2}, ..., w_{k}),$ so $\sqrt{w_{1}^{2} + ... + w_{k}^{2}} = 0$? Sorry for so many stupid questions... And I don’t know about the sign of every element in $vP^{n + 1} - v$?

Comment: If $\ \frac{w_n}{n}=\left(w_1,w_2,\dots,w_k\right)\ $ then $\ \sqrt{w_1^2+w_2^2+\dots w_k^2}\rightarrow0\ $ as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $. It is not necessarily *equal to* $0$ for any finite value of $\ n\ $.  You don't need to know anything about the signs of the entries in $\ vP^{n+1}-v\ $. Since $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{vP^{n+1}}{n}=0\ $ and $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{v}{n}=0\ $ then $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(vP^{n+1}-v\right)=0\ $ too.

Comment: Omg, I understood everything! Thank you so much